# Distinct a single column with inner join and left join coming from 3 different tables oracle pl/sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

My query is defined as below

```
select distinct
    to_number("Rental"."pkRentalId") "pkRentalId",
    to_char("Rental"."RentalNo") "RentalNo",
case when "RentedVehicle"."fkRegisteredVehicleId" is not null 
    then to_char("Vehicle"."RegistrationNumber")
    else to_char("TempVehicle"."RegistrationNumber") 
    end "VehicleRegNo"

from 
    "Rental"
    inner join "RentedVehicle" on "RentedVehicle"."fkRentalId"="Rental"."pkRentalId"
    left join "Vehicle" on "Vehicle"."pkVehicleId"="RentedVehicle"."fkRegisteredVehicleId"
    left join "TempVehicle" on "TempVehicle"."pkTempVehicleId"="RentedVehicle"."fkTempVehicleId"
```

I want my query to return the last Vehicle saved in RentedVehicle Against Rental

Rented Vehicles have several Vehicles against single Rental. but i want the last one against the rental.

Please Help.

I want

```
pkRentalId       RenatlNo            VehicleRegNo

1                  100002              KM123
2                  100003              KM123
3                  100004              LOP990
12                  100005              KM123
32                  100007              KM123
34                  100009              LOP990
```

--Tables

```
"RentedVehicle" 
   (    "pkRentedVehicleId" NUMBER(19,0), 
    "fkRegisteredVehicleId" NUMBER(19,0), 
    "fkTempVehicleId" NUMBER(19,0), 
    "fkRentalId" NUMBER(19,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "fkOutBranchId" NUMBER(19,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "fkReturnBranchId" NUMBER(19,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "CheckOutFuel" NUMBER(19,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "CheckOutOdometer" NUMBER(19,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "CheckInFuel" NUMBER(19,0), 
    "CheckInOdometer" NUMBER(19,0), 
    "TransferPointFuel" NUMBER(19,0), 
    "TransferPointOdometer" NUMBER(19,0), 
    "TotalCustomerKilometer" NUMBER(19,0), 
    "fkExchangeId" NUMBER(19,0), 
    "IsDeleted" CHAR(1 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "CreatedOn" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "CreatedBy" NUMBER(19,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "LastUpdatedOn" DATE, 
    "LastUpdatedBy" NUMBER(19,0)
)

Rental" 
   (    "pkRentalId" NUMBER(19,0), 
    "RentalNo" VARCHAR2(15 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "fkRentalStatusId" NUMBER(19,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "fkRateId" NUMBER(19,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "fkExtraId" NUMBER(19,0), 
    "fkBillingId" NUMBER(19,0), 
    "fkRateTypeId" NUMBER(19,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "fkDebtorId" NUMBER(19,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "fkSubDebtorId" NUMBER(19,0), 
    "fkBranchId" NUMBER(19,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "fkChangeTypeId" NUMBER(19,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "ChangeReason" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE), 
    "fkFromLocationId" NUMBER(19,0), 
    "fkToLocationId" NUMBER(19,0), 
    "fkCityId" NUMBER(19,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "CheckedOutOn" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "ExpectedCheckInOn" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "CheckedInOn" DATE, 
    "ReportingDateTime" DATE, 
    "ServiceInstructions" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE), 
    "DropOffRemarks" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE), 
    "IsDeleted" CHAR(1 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "CreatedOn" DATE NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "CreatedBy" NUMBER(19,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "LastUpdatedOn" DATE, 
    "LastUpdatedBy" NUMBER(19,0)
)
```

Comment: add your desired output

Comment: added. i just want the last vehicle entered against the rental... even hough 5-6 vehicles entered against 1 rental.. but i want the last one.

Comment: Do you have any date recordings for rental

Comment: yes yes.. "CreatedOn" and "LastUpdatedOn" columns

Comment: put table relations also in your question. It will be more helpful to answer

Comment: There is  no PL/SQL in your question. Where do stored procedures come into play here?

Comment: in the query, it is defined as RentedVehicle has two foreign keys pointing to Vehicle (fkRegisteredVehicleId) and TempVehicle (fkTempVehicleId).

Comment: @horse_with_no_name, do u need to see my whole package and body(with procedures in it)? or it is just good to ask about the main problem i am facing?

Comment: just add table structures

Comment: If you only have a problem with the query, then there is no need to add the PL/SQL tag (or mentioning that you are using PL/SQL)

Comment: does PL/SQL manage this type of problem in a different manner?

Answer (score 0):

Might by you can try this thing still i am not sure about it and your data

```
select 
B.pkRentalId,
B.RentalNo,
B.VehicleRegNo
from
(
select 
A.pkRentalId,
A.RentalNo,
A.VehicleRegNo,
MAX(rn) 
from 
(select 
      to_number("Rental"."pkRentalId") "pkRentalId",
    to_char("Rental"."RentalNo") "RentalNo",
case when "RentedVehicle"."fkRegisteredVehicleId" is not null 
    then to_char("Vehicle"."RegistrationNumber")
    else to_char("TempVehicle"."RegistrationNumber") 
    end "VehicleRegNo",
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY "Rental"."pkRentalId" ORDER BY "Rental"."CheckedInOn") rn

from 
    "Rental"
    inner join "RentedVehicle" on "RentedVehicle"."fkRentalId"="Rental"."pkRentalId"
    left join "Vehicle" on "Vehicle"."pkVehicleId"="RentedVehicle"."fkRegisteredVehicleId"
    left join "TempVehicle" on "TempVehicle"."pkTempVehicleId"="RentedVehicle"."fkTempVehicleId"
)   
A
group by A.pkRentalId,
A.RentalNo,
A.VehicleRegNo
) 
B
```

here i have used `"Rental"."CheckedInOn"` as vehichle date, you can change according to it.

Comment: nope. giving same Rental No's against diff vehicles.